# HAProxy error on OpenShift - Failed to execute: 'control restart'

Tags: node.js, openshift, haproxy

I am trying to configure HAProxy on OpenShift to achieve following URL based routing.

[image: HAProxy on OpenShift]

when I am trying to restart my app, I am getting following error in HAProxy log

**Starting frontend http-in: cannot bind socket**

Following are the changes I made to haproxy.cfg, in addition I have also added "user nobody" to global section. What am I doing wrong? I am new to HAProxy, so I believe it might be very basic thing I am missing.

```
frontend http-in
    bind :80
    acl is_blog url_beg /blog
    use_backend blog_gear if is_blog
    default_backend website_gear

backend blog_gear
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    server WEB1 nodejs-realspace.rhcloud.com weight 1 maxconn 512 check

backend website_gear
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    server WEB2 website-realspace.rhcloud.com weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

Comment: What errors do you see in your haproxy log on your gear?

Comment: I fixed other issue in the config(edited above). Now, I see error "Starting frontend http-in: cannot bind socket" in the HAProxy log. I have added "user nobody" in global section.

Comment: I just verified that no other process is running on port 80 as of now by running lsof -Pni | grep ":80".

Comment: I also tried binding to public IP address like 23.20.106.153:80, but that also gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To note a few problems with your configuration.

The first problem in your configuration is that you should listen on port 8080.
Ports 80, 443, 8000 an 8443 on the outside will be redirected to port 8080 on your gear.

Second website-realspace.rhcloud.com is probably the external name of your gear that also hosts your HAProxy. This means that you have created a loop.

To acces your nodejs app you'll need to use the 127.a.b.c address assigned to your gear.
Also your nodejs app should most likely cannot listen on the same port as your HAProxy.